# Affiliate program for a programming blog?

Tags: affiliate

I run a blog. I've started to get some traffic (currently approx 7000 unique visitors / month). Is that enough to make some money on ads?

If so, are there any affiliate networks targeting .NET / development?

Answer (score 1):

For your content i would look at with Skimlinks, for intext affiliate referals, really simple just set up and leave.

As for ads your coould try looking a somthing like glam media tech ad network but i think they start at arround 100k + uv per month